# Generate Canonical Tags using PHP without queries?

Tags: php, seo, canonical-link

Currently I am using the php code below to generate canonical tags globally.
It works but **I don't want queries to be appended** to the original URL.

```
<link rel="canonical" href="<?php $url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];echo $url;?>">
```

For example if the URL that is pulled dynamically is

- http://www.example.com/category/product/**umbrellas.php** (this is
  acceptable)
- http://www.example.com/category/product/**umbrellas.php?npp=72** (this 
  is not acceptable)

How can I modify my code to strip out anything after a "?" operator
~Thank You

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Answer (score 0):

As Marc B mentioned, either use parse_url to pull apart the url which is much safer than what you are doing. Or use explode to just remove anything after the ?

```
<?php
list($request_uri,$request_args) = explode('?',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],2);
echo $request_uri;
```

Note that the above is pretty nasty, use parse_url instead http://php.net/parse_url

Comment: is it risky from a security standpoint ? Also would I be able to use the code you listed above ? I'm not exactly a master coder of php.